# Select box visibility not getting triggered

Tags: jquery

i have a select whose property is set to hidden using CSS. I want to change its property to visible but i am unable to do it with following code

```
  jQuery('input:select[name=image_extension]').css("visibility", "visible");
```

can some 1 guide me here?

Comment: .Show() could work for you?

Comment: Fix your selector, that should solve the problem.

Comment: so select box shouldnt be taken as input type? i must take it as a raw selector? i mean something like this?

Comment: @noobie-php `<tag-name>` is selected with `$("tag-name")` - like for like.  A select is not an input, or the markup would be `<input type="select">`

Comment: No problem - it's easy when you know how ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery('select[name=image_extension]').css("visibility", "visible");
```

`<select>` is not `<input>` type

Answer (score 1):

Remove `input:select`

If you use `style="visibility:hidden"` in your select use

```
jQuery('select[name=image_extension]').css("visibility", "visible");
```

If you use `display:none`

```
jQuery('select[name=image_extension]').show();
```

OR

```
jQuery('select[name=image_extension]').css("display", "block");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qc3p3/1/)

Comment: If he's using visibility then it's unlikely he'll want to change the display value.

Comment: @SridharR You know why. Your answer *was* incorrect. *I want to change its property to visible* does not mention anything about `display` property

Comment: @RGraham Now its ok or not?

Comment: @SridharR Yup, it's OK now

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
jQuery('select[name="image_extension"]').css("visibility", "visible");
```